# Why does this mystic expression equal to i?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found this expression on the internet:

```
(e-e-e^(e-e))^(e^(e-e-ln(e^(e-e)-(e-e-e^(e-e)))))
```

WolframAlpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(e-e-e%5E(e-e))%5E(e%5E(e-e-ln(e%5E(e-e)-(e-e-e%5E(e-e)))))

---

My question is: why? It doesn't contain a root, negative number (or any number besides e for that matter). In fact, the only symbols used at all are the following:

- e
- (
- )
- -
- ^
- ln

Comment: This is not at all what people mean by number theory. Please change the tag to something like complex variables.

Comment: It reduces to $(-1)^{e^{-\log 2}}$.

Comment: Indeed: `(x-x-x^(x-x))^(e^(x-x-ln(x^(x-x)-(x-x-x^(x-x)))))`  is $i$ for any $x$. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wipe out all the $e-e$ terms, which cancel to zero. Your expression is

$$
(-e^0)^{\left( e^ {-\ln(e^0 -(-e^0)) } \right)}
$$

Now use $e^0
= 1$ and minus of a minus equals a plus:
$$
(-1)^{\left( e^ {-\ln(1+1)} \right)}
$$

Finally, use $e^{-ln 2} = \frac12$ to get

$$ (-1)^\frac12 = \sqrt{-1} = i
$$